# How can I grab multiple lines after a matching line in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm parsing a large file in Perl line-by-line (terminated by \n), but when I reach a certain keyword, say "TARGET", I need to grab all the lines between TARGET and the next completely empty line.

So, given a segment of a file:

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4 Target
Line 5 Grab this line
Line 6 Grab this line
\n

It should become:
Line 4 Target
Line 5 Grab this line
Line 6 Grab this line

The reason I'm having trouble is I'm already going through the file line-by-line; how do I change what I delimit by midway through the parsing process?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
my @grabbed;
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/TARGET/) {
        push @grabbed, $_;
        while (<FILE>) {
            last if /^$/;
            push @grabbed, $_;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wasn't sure if while<FILE> inside another while<FILE> was ok in perl :)

Comment: @Michael It is just another readline call, so, yes, it is OK. perldoc -f readline

Comment: If the handle isn't pointing to an actual file, but rather something like STDIN, you can have the inner while get an eof and terminate and then the outer while continue to read until *it* gets an eof. Try it with: perl -wle'print "read a"; while (<>) { print "read b"; while (<>) { print "read b" } print "read a" }'

Answer (score 14):

The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is ideal for this sort of task:

```
$ cat try
#! /usr/bin/perl

while (<DATA>) {
  print if /\btarget\b/i .. /^\s*$/
}

__DATA__
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4 Target
Line 5 Grab this line
Line 6 Grab this line

Nope
Line 7 Target
Linu 8 Yep

Nope again

$ ./try
Line 4 Target
Line 5 Grab this line
Line 6 Grab this line

Line 7 Target
Linu 8 Yep
```

Answer (score 10):

The short answer: line delimiter in perl is `$/`, so when you hit TARGET, you can set `$/` to `"\n\n"`, read the next "line", then set it back to "\n"... et voilà!

Now for the longer one: if you use the `English` module (which gives sensible names to all of Perl's magic variable, then `$/` is called `$RS` or `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`. If you use `IO::Handle`, then `IO::Handle->input_record_separator( "\n\n")` will work.

And if you're doing this as part of a bigger piece of code, don't forget to either localize (using `local $/;` in the appropriate scope) or to set back `$/` to its original value of `"\n"`.

Comment: I like how you explained the way to do this without giving code. It is a little longer, but in the end the reader is better off to do something similar in the future.

Comment: If you `use English;` (which I don't, but whatever floats your boat) be sure to `use English '-no_match_vars';`, otherwise you'll get a performance hit with regular expressions.

Comment: @Chris Lutz you are right, I just assumed that if you use English, then you would read the docs.

Answer (score 4):

From [perlfaq6](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html)'s answer to [How can I pull out lines between two patterns that are themselves on different lines?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How_can_I_pull_out_l)

---

You can use Perl's somewhat exotic .. operator (documented in perlop):

```
perl -ne 'print if /START/ .. /END/' file1 file2 ...
```

If you wanted text and not lines, you would use

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /START(.*?)END/gs' file1 file2 ...
```

But if you want nested occurrences of START through END, you'll run up against the problem described in the question in this section on matching balanced text.

Here's another example of using ..:

```
while (<>) {
    $in_header =   1  .. /^$/;
    $in_body   = /^$/ .. eof;
# now choose between them
} continue {
    $. = 0 if eof;  # fix $.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(<FILE>)
{
    if (/target/i)
    {
        $buffer .= $_;
        while(<FILE>)
        {
            $buffer .= $_;
            last if /^\n$/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inside = 0;
my $data = '';
while (<DATA>) {
    $inside = 1 if /Target/;
    last if /^$/ and $inside;
    $data .= $_ if $inside;
}

print '[' . $data . ']';

__DATA__
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4 Target
Line 5 Grab this line
Line 6 Grab this line

Next Line
```

Edit to fix the exit condition as per the note below.

Comment: I'd be against flags, but this is one of the clearest i've seen so far!

Comment: d0h! I should change that to "last if /^$/ and $inside;" to handle the case where there is a blank line before the target.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind ugly auto-generated code, and assuming you just want lines between `TARGET` and the next empty line, and want all the other lines to be dropped, you can use the output of this command:

```
s2p -ne '/TARGET/,/^$/p'
```

(Yes, this is a hint that this problem is usually much more easily solved in `sed`. :-P)

Comment: See gbacon's answer. This could be written as "perl -ne 'print if /TARGET/ .. /^$/'" which is more or less exactly what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I seldom come back to check for other people's answers, so it's good that there is a clearly more superior answer given.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one loop (modifying Dave Hinton's code):

```
my @grabbed;
my $grabbing = 0;
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/TARGET/ ) {
       $grabbing = 1;
    } elsif( /^$/ ) {
       $grabbing = 0;
    }
    if ($grabbing) {
        push @grabbed, @_;
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at some of the other examples here... $flags should be avoided as this is 'perl' code, and as such you should be using perl-isms.

Comment: @Ape-inago Can you explain? (I just noticed that i use 'flags' in code elsewhere)

Comment: Use flags if that's what makes sense to you.  'Any level of language proficiency is acceptable in Perl culture.  We won't send the language police after you.  A Perl script is "correct" if it gets the job done before your boss fires you.' - Larry Wall

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<IN>) {
print OUT if (/Target/../^$/) ; 
}
```